# How to change ErrorAttributes of ResponseStatusException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

How can I change the error attributes that are exposed when throwing a `ResponseStatusException`?

Especially I want to hide the `exception`, `error` and `status` type in the json, but only during production.

```
    @RestController
    public class MyController {
       @GetMapping("/test")
       public Object get() {
          throw new org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException(
                 HttpStatus.Forbidden, "some message");
       }
    }
```

Result:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-11-06T12:16:50.111+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException",
    "message": "some message",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

Comment: I suppose you do have multiple profiles like: dev, prod ... Also, you do not use Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes I have multiple profiles.

Comment: May I ask you again: do not use Spring Boot?

Comment: Excuse me, yes I'm also using spring-boot. Added the tag.

Answer (score 4):

It's configure using [DefaultErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html#resolveException-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Exception-)

`public DefaultErrorAttributes(boolean includeException)`

> Create a new `DefaultErrorAttributes` instance.
>
> Parameters:
>
> includeException - whether to include the "exception" attribute

Notice the default is without

```
public DefaultErrorAttributes()
```

> Create a new `DefaultErrorAttributes` instance that does not include the "exception" attribute.

See [example of customizing error](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/06/spicy-spring-custom-error-json-response-with-errorattributes/)

Comment: So i would override  `DefaultErrorAttributes` and `errorAttributes.remove("path")` etc?

Comment: @membersound Or call `Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, false);
`

Comment: @membersound IMO this answer clearly solve the problem: make an implementation of DefaultErrorAttributes for each profile.